# Enable pasting into input[type='date']?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, paste

It seems that a `<input type='date' />` cannot be pasted into in Chrome. I've tried all sorts of formats including yyyy-MM-dd MM/dd/yyyy and even just pasting one component at a time (just the month or just the year) but nothing happens. I'm working in an angular app and I even tried setting up an `onpaste` event to push the pasted contents into an angular model but it never fires.

Here's what I have:

HTML

```
<input date-field type='date' ng-model='dateOfBirth'/>
```

Angular Directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularcoreApp').directive('dateField', function($filter) {
  return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        element[0].addEventListener('paste', function () {
          debugger;
          alert(arguments);
        }, false);
        ngModelController.$parsers = [];
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
          //View -> Model
          var date = Date.parseExact(data, "yyyy-MM-dd");
          ngModelController.$setValidity('date', date!=null);
          return date;
        });
        ngModelController.$formatters = [];
        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
          //Model -> View
          return $filter('date')(data, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        });
       }
    }
});
```

I import datejs as well.

Currently I never hit the `debugger` statement in the paste event listener. No error is thrown and it doesn't seem that any value is entered into the view or the model.

How can I allow a date to be pasted into this input?

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was something like this:

```
const input = document.getElementById('my-input');

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
  if (document.activeElement !== input) {
    return;
  }

  const value = e.clipboardData.getData('text');

  input.value = value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem in 2016 and found it possible to workaround this by wrapping inputs in other elements.

```
<div id="wrapped" onpaste="alert(11)">
    <input type="date" id="input1">
</div>
```

Knowing that div's are ok for "paste" event one can modify input data.